# NextJS13 Mouse Wheel Event Not Working for Scroll Transitions in Chrome

Tags: reactjs, typescript, scroll, tailwind-css, next.js13

At the beginning of the full-stack training project I started, I got bored and tried to implement the ideas that came to my mind. One of them was to create a homepage with a single-page application (SPA) look. For this, I created a component that would implement scroll transitions, and I wanted this component to listen to both keyboard and mouse wheel events to navigate to the previous or next section. The mouse wheel event, which works perfectly in Firefox, does not work in Chrome. I looked into it by adding console.log statements in various places, and I observed that mouse wheel movements are being detected, but the transitions are not happening. Can you help me with this? I'm sending the Github repo link and the relevant component's code.

**What I tried:** I have created a single-page application (SPA) component with scroll transitions that listen to both keyboard and mouse wheel events. The component successfully navigates to the previous or next section based on keyboard input, and it correctly detects mouse wheel movements.

**What I was expecting:** I expected the mouse wheel events to trigger smooth scroll transitions in Chrome, similar to how they work in Firefox. However, in Chrome, the transitions are not working despite detecting mouse wheel movements. I would like to understand why this behavior is occurring and find a solution to make it work as expected.

[`Github Repo.`](https://github.com/RicochetBiscuit/nextjs_project)
[`Vercel Link`](https://nextjs-project-onfpezskj-ricochetbiscuit.vercel.app/)

Scroll component:

```
import { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";

interface SectionData {
  name: string;
  className?: string;
  image?: string;
  title?: string;
  text?: string;
  textStyle?: string;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}

const sectionsData: SectionData[] = [];

const Scroll = ({ sectionsData }: { sectionsData: SectionData[] }) => {
  const sectionRefs = sectionsData.map(() =>
    useRef<null | HTMLDivElement>(null)
  );
  const [currentSectionIndex, setCurrentSectionIndex] = useState<number>(0);

  const scrollToSection = (index: number) => {
    const ref = sectionRefs[index];
    if (ref.current) {
      ref.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
      setCurrentSectionIndex(index);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = (event: { deltaY: number }) => {
      if (event.deltaY > 0) {
        if (currentSectionIndex < sectionsData.length - 1) {
          console.log("downed");
          scrollToSection(currentSectionIndex + 1);
        }
      } else {
        if (currentSectionIndex > 0) {
          console.log("upped");
          scrollToSection(currentSectionIndex - 1);
        }
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("wheel", handleScroll);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("wheel", handleScroll);
    };
  }, [currentSectionIndex]);

  return (
    <>
      {sectionsData.map((section, index) => (
        <section
          key={index}
          ref={sectionRefs[index]}
          className={`${section.className}`}
          style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${section.image})` }}
        >
          {section.title && <h1>{section.title}</h1>}
          {section.text && (
            <p className={`${section.textStyle}`}>{section.text}</p>
          )}
          {section.children}
          {index < sectionsData.length - 1 && (
            <div className="flex items-center justify-center h-screen">
              <div className="p-6 bg-amber-200 opacity-50 hover:opacity-100 transition-opacity rounded-lg shadow-lg">
                <button onClick={() => scrollToSection(index + 1)}>
                  Go to the {sectionsData[index + 1].name}
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </section>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
export default Scroll;
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix it with scrollTo function but why this working other is not, I have no idea..

```
import { useRef, useEffect, useState, useContext, createContext } from "react";

interface SectionData {
  name: string;
  auto?: boolean;
  className?: string;
  image?: string;
  textStyle?: string;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}

const ScrollContext = createContext({
  scrollToSection: (index: number) => {},
});

export const useScroll = () => useContext(ScrollContext);

const Scroll = ({ sectionsData }: { sectionsData: SectionData[] }) => {
  const sectionRefs = sectionsData.map(() =>
    useRef<null | HTMLDivElement>(null)
  );
  const [currentSectionIndex, setCurrentSectionIndex] = useState<number>(0);

  const scrollToSection = (index: number) => {
    const ref = sectionRefs[index];
    if (ref.current) {
      const top = ref.current.offsetTop;
      window.scrollTo({
        top,
        behavior: "smooth",
      });
      setCurrentSectionIndex(index);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = (event: { deltaY: number }) => {
      if (event.deltaY > 0) {
        if (currentSectionIndex < sectionsData.length - 1) {
          scrollToSection(currentSectionIndex + 1);
        }
      } else {
        if (currentSectionIndex > 0) {
          scrollToSection(currentSectionIndex - 1);
        }
      }
    };

    const handleKeyDown = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
      if (event.key === "ArrowDown") {
        if (currentSectionIndex < sectionsData.length - 1) {
          scrollToSection(currentSectionIndex + 1);
        }
      } else if (event.key === "ArrowUp") {
        if (currentSectionIndex > 0) {
          scrollToSection(currentSectionIndex - 1);
        }
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("wheel", handleScroll);
    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("wheel", handleScroll);
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
    };
  }, [currentSectionIndex]);
  return (
    <ScrollContext.Provider value={{ scrollToSection }}>
      <>
        {sectionsData.map((section, index) => (
          <section
            key={index}
            ref={sectionRefs[index]}
            className={`${section.className} ${
              section.auto !== undefined
                ? section.auto
                  ? "h-auto"
                  : "h-screen"
                : "h-screen"
            }`}
            style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${section.image})` }}
          >
            {section.children}
          </section>
        ))}
      </>
    </ScrollContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default Scroll;
```